# Leaflet Selecting Map Objects but Only When Flexbox

Tags: javascript, flexbox, leaflet, selection

I'm seeing very strange behavior with Leaflet in Firefox, but not Chrome or IE/Edge. Essentially, when the map container is `display: flex`, all its objects that I can see are selected when I click. If I start dragging, the selection happens when I pick up the mouse.

It looks like "text" selection, but I'm not sure. It does not behave like normal text selection, as, usually, the item gets selected when you drag over it, while here, it gets selected when you click on it, or, technically, when you let go of your mouse. My best guess is flexbox alters some of the calculations Leaflet does to determine when dragging is happening.

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rxjb3a3vgmTUEUnPPSQF?p=preview) of the behavior. On Firefox, if you click the top map, it gets selected. If you click the bottom map, nothing unusual happens.

Firefox version: 52.0.1 (32-bit)
Google Chrome version: 57.0.2987.133
Internet Explorer version: 11.0.9600.18617
Edge version: 38.14393.0.0, EdgeHTML version: 14.14393

Comment: Why not wrap the leaflet map container in another element, set the wrapper to `display: flex` and the leaflet map container to 100% width/height of the wrapper?

Comment: This is a good idea. However, if something strange like this happens on 1 leaflet element, it may happen on others. It is sometimes not possible or extremely difficult to use wrappers like this.

Comment: Encountered this same problem, solved by moving flex to the wrapper element like @IvanSanchez proposed.